# Can't install gmpy on Windows

Tags: python, pip, gmpy

I tried to `pip install gmpy` but it didn't work.

Here's the error:

```
PS C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads> pip install gmpy
Collecting gmpy
  Using cached gmpy-1.17.zip (147 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy
  Building wheel for gmpy (pyproject.toml) ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for gmpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      gmpy.c
      src/gmpy.c(243): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gmpy
Failed to build gmpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gmpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

However, `pip install gmpy2` and others worked.

I tried to import both of them:

[image]

Here's the part I need to calculate:

```py
N = 17740803753336460891508014077951088945415214329359164945595622460861617151883658129377771074141448545977293824812472806768754107334272113784618671425945265453677763300584120796664192793654787317526905676618168560287204392207536711238413377822113265783504873957094131330620182217422910507867161033695120195691266283498385072573721376398480018719760538723050237163598524153522595496137288270407836138586188296538117138982579560625325815068701431157466298638302885600982291990551448117534677697122276691651611734934147801954625280213769902451417946572231015611006746186167211313556716518863585799128114202130873384852581
e = 65537
ct = 7617664236008252568996899627946125782926068188323112773389474654757630578865481085502759186904920518615173703165984894164411436709177950136929724052191922739861682189280802963747906815275683543148623167088950096943169566195634558711652670745197446307315888349532981492405588457559228674864147994684328968321710022127803384848143475788457274558988285904875669797926919759123645348144531804252200718312650929926931919262408975771593313266992606751663814830129337536342634243623652919127335934704778878412649409415730419077839365246227059700689395639431013008985996793686430486195007712091309878718060405038405039494286
a = sqrt(N) +1 
b = (a*a) - N # if I use gmpy2 instead of gmpy, the result will be wrong
#p = a - sqrt((b)) gmpy2 return b as a negative number, so I can't calculate p
p = 133194608574583306560585537741344865434566457335756913474195376386565743253745136529892878182973405477415063521701522490974580141634005077732157132519942995782242635825758964371685299620951981666567270659322471350406909271667819474931143113141023059424058315681431599980321513448212682539665160717948701866681 
# for this result, I used gmpy in sagemath in Ubuntu.
```

Answer (score 0):

[gmpy](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy/) is no longer maintained, you should use `gmpy2`. In this case what you need is `gmpy2.isqrt(n)` which return the integer part of the square root of n.

The difference between `isqrt` and `sqrt` in `gmpy2` is that `sqrt` support floating numbers but it can't be used for big numbers in cryptography.

source:

- [isqrt](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html#gmpy2.isqrt)
- [sqrt](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html#gmpy2.sqrt)

Comment: Well but it seems like the gmpy2.sqrt() returns the wrong values (not the one that I expected). I tried to solve a CTF challenge which need to calculate a sqrt(big_num), while `gmpy.sqrt()` in Ubuntu runs fine and returns the right value, `gmpy2.sqrt()` returns some negative number.

Comment: @LilLee what are you trying to solve exactly? if you want to find the integer result, you can use gmpy2.isqrt() (it's equivalent to gmpy.sqrt() since it only accept integer)

Comment: @ BlueBeret I have edited the question, adding more details about the RSA-related challenge, I don't know what's the difference between gmpy2.sqrt() and gmpy.sqrt(). I tried gmpy2.isqrt() and it worked!

Comment: @LilLee Happy to help, I have updated my answer and please mark that as accepted if it answers your question. I was ctf player too :D